# HTML Script For tags is creating extra space

Tags: html, tags

I've been trying to implement an automatic tag with an app for all of my products on Shopify. It works so that the tag created pulls information from the product desciption. If the description states "Pre-order. Ships in 2-3 weeks." or "Pre-order. Ships January 2021." It will pull whatever appears after the the word "Ships in" or Ships". As a result, the tags appear as such:

- preorder**2-3 weeks
- preorder**January 2021

The tag is used to insert estimated shipping times throughout the site.

The issue right now is that some of the tags have a space after "preorder** " and we need to make sure there is never a space. Any ideas on how to fix? The Body HTML that it is based off is *if* it contains "Pre-order. Ships in". Here's our current code:

```
   {% assign body = product.body_html | strip_html | newline_to_br %}
   {% assign keywords = "Pre-order. Ships" %}

  b{% assign tags = '' %}
 {% if body contains keywords %}
    {% assign lines = body | split: "<br />" %}
        {% for line in lines %}
       {% if line contains keywords %}
           {% assign tokens = line | split: keywords %}
        {% if tokens.size == 2 %}
            {% assign inner_tokens = tokens[1] | split: "." %}
            {% if inner_tokens.size >= 1 %}
                {% assign value = inner_tokens[0] | replace: "in", "" | escape_once | replace: "&nbsp;", "" %}
                {% assign tag = "preorder**" | append:value | replace_first: " ", "" %}
                {% assign tags = tags | append: tag | append: ',' %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
 {{ tags }}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

The issue is happening because "Ships in " has one more space than "Ships ".

#### Solution

You need to remove the space after the "in".

You can do this easily by modifying your `replace` operator

#### Code

`replace: "in", ""` becomes `replace: "in ", ""` (note the space).

Your code becomes:

```
   {% assign body = product.body_html | strip_html | newline_to_br %}
   {% assign keywords = "Pre-order. Ships" %}

  b{% assign tags = '' %}
 {% if body contains keywords %}
    {% assign lines = body | split: "<br />" %}
        {% for line in lines %}
       {% if line contains keywords %}
           {% assign tokens = line | split: keywords %}
        {% if tokens.size == 2 %}
            {% assign inner_tokens = tokens[1] | split: "." %}
            {% if inner_tokens.size >= 1 %}
                {% assign value = inner_tokens[0] | replace: "in ", "" | escape_once | replace: "&nbsp;", "" %}
                {% assign tag = "preorder**" | append:value | replace_first: " ", "" %}
                {% assign tags = tags | append: tag | append: ',' %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
 {{ tags }}
```

Comment: Hey! Apprecciate this. Just wanted to double check to make sure that this won't allow any of the tags to include the word "in"? And that all this does is ensure there is no space? Let me know! Thank you!

Comment: I just ran the tag on all my products and some of them say, for example, "b preorder**in4-5 weeks". Is there any way we could make sure it doesn't do that?